# Call realgud from certain directory

Tags: realgud

I need to call realgud from a certain directory, because my python cant be called from another directory. How do I do that?

I need to call it from a root directory and my python program where the main is in the source directory.

Comment: Does cd not work?https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36980/5223

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rusi